# operator new [] argument value

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have found difference between arguments values for operator new [] when my class has destructor and hasn't.
See next code please:

```
class A
{
public: 
    ~A()
    {
    }

    void *operator new (size_t size)
    {
        return malloc(size);
    }

    void operator delete (void *p)
    {
        free(p);
    }

    void *operator new[] (size_t size)
    {
        return malloc(size);
    }

    void operator delete[] (void *p)
    {
        free(p);
    }

    void *operator new(size_t size, void *p)
    {
        return p;
    }

private:
    int m_a;
};

int main()
{
    size_t size = 50;
    A *p_a = new A[size];
    delete[] p_a;
}
```

I have experemented and ran this code with commented and uncommented Destructor definition.
In the first case size value was 200
In the second case size value was 204

I always knew that we allocate some more memory for arrays to have a knowleges about array size. But I didn't know that overhead memory depends on Destructor presence.

I can mean that compiler doesn't need to additional memory if it doesn't need to iterate by memory block and to call destructors.

If anybody has any other ideas or references to standart give me them :)

Comment: That was quick, @coderredoc

Comment: The relevant reference is presumably the Itanium ABI for C++, section "array cookies".

Comment: Please provide the example of what returns 200.

Comment: What C++ compiler and on what platform? There are tens of C++ compilers and a lot of platforms.

Comment: FYI: On Windows 10 with MSVC 19.12.25907 for x64 the `void* operator new[](size_t)` is called with 208.

Comment: https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#array-cookies

Comment: @coderredoc Actually, that is false. However `C != ++C` :D

Comment: @klutt.: :D haha ...

Comment: Got it, The `void* operator new[](size_t)` is called with `sizeof(size_t) +  sizeof(T) * size` where the size from your example is 50 and the T is int. Because you are executing your example on 32 bit  platform therefore the size_t is 4. The sum of these values are 204. The malloc allocates 204 bytes and the operator new return with the allocated pointer. After the CRT stores the size on the allocated memory, adds a 4 byte offset and store with the offset-ed pointer into the p_a. On 64bit platform the size of allocated memory is 208 byte because the sizeof size_t is 8 byte,

Comment: Different isn't the same. -- Fred Picker

Comment: Thank You all friends, but the point of question was: why current behavior depends on the fact has a class Destructor or not?